# AJAX, PHP, Javascript and HTML file structuring

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This might be an abstract question but hopefully I can explain my problem well enough.

I have a PHP file with HTML code that has text boxes and a submit button. This is the main page. It is called `mainHTML.php`

These text boxes have the following form

```
<form action="tableHTML.php" method="get">
```

When the submit button is clicked, `tableHTML.php` is launched.

`tableHTML.php` has a AJAX script which checks the value of a select box described in the same file `tableHTML.php`. This AJAX script will be used to append the PHP string that will be used to query the database.

This script calls as its url `tableCode.php` and gives it (through POST) the value of the select box.

This file also contains the connection and query to a database in php. From the info acquired in this file, I made a javascript function that makes a table out of the data acquired.

At this point I have three files with 2 or more languages in each and it seems like a mess. I don't know where to start to sort these out. The Ajax is what introduced the problem. Are there any conventions I can follow to sort my code out so that Ajax can be implemented without creating errors in my code?

Again very abstract question but any reading materials/advice would be welcome.

Thank you

Comment: "The Ajax is what introduced the problem" — That's surprising. PHP tries so hard to be both a template language and a programming language that it is usually responsible for that sort of nastiness. It's hard to tell what you're looking for though. You seem to have identified the problem. Stop mixing languages. Keep your business logic, display logic, and data layer as separate as possible.

Comment: tableHTML can't have data of mainHTML.php

Comment: @Quentin If for example, I have to merge two files which each contain JS code and PHP code, I should put PHP in one file and JS in the other? If yes, how can I access a specific JS function when a specific PHP code is executed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

order your project file system (Directory Structure):

```
project_folder
-public_html
--css
--styles
--images
---content
---layout
--js
--index.php
-resources
--config.php
--library
---slimframework(for example)
--templates
```

and require files according to the structure shown.

Better you manage the project by adopting MVC pattern.
The minimal directory strucutre is:

```
MVCProject
-content
--bootstrap.css
--style.css
-controllers
-views
-models
```

You must separate presentation logic with business logic. This help you to create reusable code for other projects and testing.
This is a great site on patterns : http://www.oodesign.com/ 
I hope to be proved helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your project using the MVC pattern.

[image]

You can do it yourself but **don't reinvent the wheel**

You may want to use a framework like Codeigniter, Lavaral, etc.

More info can be found [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132275/php-web-application-architecture-design).

Thanks.